# PHP regular expression pattern allows unwanted literal asterisks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression that allows only specific characters from the name fields in an HTML form, namely letters, white space, single quotes, hyphens and periods. Here is the pattern:

```
return mb_ereg_match("^[\w\s'-\.]+$", $name);
```

Problem is this pattern, for some reason, returns true when there are literal asterisks in $name. This shouldn't be possible unless I'm missing something. I've done multiple searches on literal asterisks and all I found was the `"\*"` pattern for intentionally matching them.

The same pattern in preg_match() also returns a match when passed a string like "*John".

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: On a side note, try to avoid using the ereg_* functions as they are **deprecated** as of PHP 5.3.0. Scripts using ereg_* functions are **not** future-proof and will break when you (or your hosting service) upgrade to PHP 5.3. You should use preg_* instead.

Comment: I went to check the above assertion but I'm not sure anymore, since the warning that's on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php is not on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php. Can anybody confirm that the mb_ereg_* functions are deprecated as well?

Comment: @NicNLD: According to [this post](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/268091-ereg-and-deprecated-error/#entry1376285), mb_ereg_* functions aren't on the deprecation list.

Comment: @Beardy, thanks for the rectification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a double-backslash in front of these codes. One to escape the backslash, one to escape the escape sequence.

You also need to escape the `-`, otherwise it accepts all characters "between" `'` and `.`.

```
return mb_ereg_match("^[\\w\\s'\\-\\.]+$", $name);
```

Have a look at a working case (using `preg_match`): http://ideone.com/E8afAM

Comment: Instead of escaping `-` you can make it the first or last character in the class

Comment: @TomSmilack Correct. (But, in my opinion, it's good to escape it anyway, to avoid things like this.)

Answer (score 0):

When enclosed in square-brackets, the hyphen acts as a special character to denote a range. In your case, it's matching all characters in the range `'` to `.`.

Escaping the hyphen should return the desired result:

```
^[\w\s'\-\.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a regular expression that allows only specific characters from the name fields in an HTML form, namely letters, white space, single quotes, hyphens and periods.

You miss, that `\w` is not a *letter* character. [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) says:

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word".

And, the [perl definition](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) is:

> A `\w` matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic character, or a decimal digit) or a *connecting punctuation* character, such as an underscore ("_").

The *connecting punctuation* character *should* mean only `_` as i read, but this is maybe a multibyte extension's bug.

If you use `mb_ereg_match` only for whole unicode matches, give a try to `preg_match`'s [`/u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) & the [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) feature, since php 5.1.0